# Submit method don't work in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I need to replace submit button to "link_to".

```
#View
<%= form_for :task, remote: true, id: 'create_form' do |f| %>
  ....
  <%= link_to 'OK', '', id: 'submit_link' %>
<% end %>


#CoffeeScript
ready = ->
  $("#submit_link").click (event) ->
    $("#create_form").submit()
$(document).ready ready
$(document).on "page:load", ready
```

Click trigger work good, but "submit()" method doesn't work and i don't know why.
Also i try to add "event.preventDefault()", but nothing changed.

Comment: You are missing `#`

Comment: ops. Sorry, i missing # only in this post. In my code i have it.

Comment: try `$("#create_form")[0].submit()`

Comment: @trueinViso, no, also doesn't work

Comment: Do you see any javascript errors in the console before or after you hit submit?

Comment: @trueinViso, nothing. I watched in chrome developer console and in rails development log.

Comment: I also print script in js, but doesn't work. Only test alert work.

`$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit_link').click(function (event) {
    alert('wooork')
    $('#create_form').submit();
  })
});
`

Comment: Can you check if `$("#create_form")` in console gives you the correct form node ?

Comment: @lorefnon sorry, but i'm new in rails and don't know how it do.

Comment: Open browser dev tools and in console tab enter `$("#create_form").length` and check the output

Comment: @lorenfon thank you. 
Result:
`$("#create_form").length
=> 0`

Comment: With `f.submit` all work good, but not the `submit()` method in js.

Comment: Can you confirm that the form id is in fact `create_form`? I'm not sure you can set the id of a form this way with simple_form

Comment: @HarlemSquirrel, no, i don't know how i can confirm it. I also have suspicions that this set id way wrong, but i haven't found anything about id set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set the id of your form like this

```
<%= form_for :task, remote: true, html: { id: 'create_form' } do |f| %>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Or, just use the form id that `form_for` generates which should be `new_task`

```
#CoffeeScript
ready = ->
  $("#submit_link").click (event) ->
    $("#new_task").submit()
$(document).ready ready
$(document).on "page:load", ready
```

Comment: With this change, what does `$("#create_form").length` output?

Comment: @HermanEyd if you don't really need to set the form id then I would use the one `form_for` generates. See my edited answer.

Comment: wow, magic. For the first time dont't work with `<%= form_for :task, remote: true, html: { id: 'create_form' } do |f| %>`, but now all work only with this change! Thank you! It's great!